# char* as function return value with Unity plugin

Tags: plugins, char, unity-game-engine

I would like to use char* as a return value (like it is done in Unity's example plugin) but I get some invalid markings (效汬o) instead of simple "Hello". Any ideas what could be wrong?

DLL:

```
extern "C"
{
    const __declspec(dllexport) char*  PrintHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Unity:

```
public class audiotest : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [DllImport("ASimplePlugin")]
    private static extern IntPtr PrintHello();

    void Start ()
    {
        Debug.Log(Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(PrintHello()));
    }
}
```

Unity's example plugin can be found http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Images/manual/SimplestPluginExample-4.0.zip

I am using Unity 4.2.1f4 and Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PtrToStringAnsi instead of PtrToStringAuto.

Your DLL is returning an ANSI string, but PtrToStringAuto expects Unicode on anything except Windows 98.